# No attribute found HandTrackingModule in PyCham

Tags: python, mediapipe, cvzone

I am working on a mini-project *(AI VIRTUAL MOUSE)*
I'm using **Python 3.8.0(x86 64-bit) & Pycham(2022.1)**
I've Installed Libraries & modules such as: **NumPy,autopy,OpenCV-python,HandTrackingModule & media pipe**
after writing the code I got this error

**AttributeError: module 'HandTrackingModule' has no attribute 'handDetector'**

Please guide me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if your using cvzone install it and use
`from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector`
If it still doesn't work, then it would be pragmatc if you share some code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).